# How can I scale media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

Ahoy...

I'm doing an Ember application, and I need to be able to scale the layout, as it sometimes needs to be displayed on large panels, where I can't get the pixel ratio. (oh, *and* all the way down to iPhone screens as well...)

So, here's my problem:
I've made the whole thing totally scalable and dandy, but I *do* also need to use a bunch of media queries here and there.

Now, while I can scale the application (fonts etc.) up and down with my JS skillz, the general layout remains the same, as the media queries are unchanged. This obviously makes everything look somewhat distorted.

What I need is basically to be able to apply a scaling factor to the limits in my media queries.

I realise that a workaround would be to change the meta tag for the screen width, but that's a no-go, as we need device pixel = actual pixel for the cleanest rendering (many Androids look fuzzy with pixel ratio e.g. 1.75).

I've looked at using calc(..) in the media queries (doesn't work). As I'm using Ember, I have access to all the templates and stuff. I'm thinking along the lines of calculating it all in JS and shoving it into the DOM in a STYLE tag, but with ~100 media queries, I imagine it will get painful... And keep me from lager in the weekend... So here's me drafting... No pun intended...

EDIT:

Seems I haven't stressed a key issue enough: The MQs need to be changeable client-side. As mentioned, the application needs to run on wall-mount TV screens of arbitrary size, so while they probably all have HD or HD-ready resolution, the PPI varies a lot, and the only way to obtain the appropriate scale of the design, is to fire the thing up and scale it to fit in the app config. Just going with plain ol' MQs won't cut it.

Comment: Are your measurement units in pixels, or something more sensible like em, rem and %?

Comment: This sounds like a general responsive design question. I wouldn't do anything crazy with JavaScript like this as Sass/CSS probably provide all the tools you need. One small improvement which may be useful is responsive elements, which is indeed a framework using JavaScript, but will probably be a standard one day anyway, and you don't have to use JavaScript yourself - see http://kumailht.com/responsive-elements/.

Comment: @gabe3886 That should be the answer to this question. Media queries in `em` or `ch` work very well and are perfectly suitable for this kind of situation.

Comment: Agree with @mahemoff and Mr Lister. Determine at what dimensions your layout breaks down and write media queries for those boundaries.

Comment: Thanks guys, but it still doesn't cut it. I do use which doesn't run client side, so it still leaves me stuck in the mud, as I need to scale runtime (see edit). I obviously did make everything scalable, not using px in the CSS at all, except the MQs (which are, IMHO, very rigid and poorly designed but that's another story). As the panels are pretty dumb, I can't use any fancy MQ-stuff like pixel ratio. The only way is manual adjustment - which necessitates a client side solution. I could use LESS, but as we're already using SASS, this will complicate the codebase quite a lot, which is a no go.

Comment: ...and by "manual adjustment", I mean that the user needs to be able to do it in a config menu or something. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Following the positive feedback from my comment, I've created this as an answer to help people viewing this question down the line.

When creating an application or website which needs to scale from small devices up to large screens, it is always best to use easily scalable units of measurement.  This means avoiding the use of `px` in your CSS.

The following units should be used for the best cross-device compatibility and scalability:

%.  The percentage of the screen to measure.  e.g. `100%` is 100% of the screen, `50%` is half of the screen, and so on.  Fairly straight forward.

rem.  The size relative to the root element em size.  This means that whatever the base font size is for the document, everything scales in relation to that.  If the base font size is 16px and you set something to be 1.5rem, then it will be 24px; 1.5 x 16px.  This is ideal when adding accessibility and allowing users to increase the font size themselves.

em (where things can get complicated). This is the size relative to the direct parent container font size.  It's similar to `rem` (see above), but will multiply the further down the structure you go.

Assume the following css:

```
html {
    font-size : 16px;
}

div {
    font-size : 1.5em;
}
```

When we couple this with nested divs, things can get frustrating:

```
<div>
    <!-- font-size is 24px !-->
    <div>
        <!-- font-size is 36px !-->
        <div>
            <!-- font-size is 54px !-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use `em`'s carefully as you can find things scaling very rapidly when you didn't expect it.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for that.  It's habit more than anything now.  I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the response! :o) I do use pixels ONLY ONCE in my CSS: the html tag font-size. Everything else is em, rem or %. I can easily scale up and down. But when I scale things up, I essentially make the screen smaller - without actually making it smaller. So, the MQs won't lift a finger, as they trigger on screen pixel size, which doesn't change when I scale things. Mixing pixel ratio into the MQs won't cut it, as this must be set to one for best rendering on certain devices. I, naively, tried rem in the MQs, which obviously didn't work, as they were fixed at the default size.